# Vulkan Queue submission synchronization - vkWaitForFences vs vkQueueWaitIdle

Tags: vulkan

I have single time command which I want to end and submit in the method.

Is there a difference between do it like (1):

```c
vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);
    
VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;

VkFence fence;
VkFenceCreateInfo fenceInfo{};
fenceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FENCE_CREATE_INFO;
fenceInfo.flags = VK_FENCE_CREATE_SIGNALED_BIT;
vkCreateFence(device, &fenceInfo, nullptr, &fence);

vkQueueSubmit(submitQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &fence, VK_TRUE, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());

vkFreeCommandBuffers(device, commandPool, 1, &commandBuffer);
```

and like this (2):

```c
vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;

vkQueueSubmit(submitQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

vkQueueWaitIdle(submitQueue);

vkFreeCommandBuffers(device, commandPool, 1, &commandBuffer);
```

As I read somewhere `vkQueueWaitIdle` should be just something like *"special case of fence"*, but is it really like this? I also crossed over the information that `vkQueueWaitIdle` should be avoided as it is at most as good as using the `vkWaitForFences`.
Is the first code snippet with usage of the fence ok, or I misunderstood some principle of the fence usage? And does it - in this case - matter at all if the first or second synchro method is used?

Comment: This is one of those XY problems, where you should basically *never* want to write this code. A function that not only submits work, but stalls its thread until that work has completed, is not a good idea if performance is a thing that matters to you.

Comment: In your example either method would work, both halt the thread until the submitted work has completed.  In general however the only time you would use `vkQueueWaitIdle` over a fence is for situations where you don't really care about performance, e.g. loading some resources for a demo, or waiting for the queue to finish before shutting down the app.  A fence is normally used to synchronise one-or-more worker threads.  Incidentally you would need to pass the fence as an argument to `vkQueueSubmit`.

Comment: In your snippet, you actually forgot to use the `fence` in the `vkQueueSubmit`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. As this use case is to free single time command buffer after calling vkQueueSubmit I should put the fence to vkQueueSubmit call and then "somewhere" check for this fence if is signaled. And if it is, call the vkFreeCommandBuffers for that command buffer. Am I right that as it is synchronziation of application cmd calls I should be using fences and not semaphores as these are used for GPU internal synchronization? This way I can avoid to use vkQueueWaitIdle and vkWaitForFences, both, I assume.

Comment: @NicolBolas `stalls its thread until that work has completed, is not a good idea if performance is a thing that matters to you.` So.. What is the most performant way to upload data from a host-visible (staging buffer) into a device-local with a dedicated transfer queue available? In every example I see, they create a command buffer, add a copy command into it and summit the command buffer into the transfer queue and wait for it to finish.

Comment: @BrodaJarek3: "*In every example I see*" I would not take performance advice from any Vulkan "example" that is not *specifically* about performance. Tutorials and example code tend to be written to make the code readable and correct, not fast.

Comment: @krOoze: Yes, as it seems as more or less same question like mine, but it was already clear from these comments above, but these cannot be accepted as an answer.

Comment: @CJ_Notned It is newer. Just making ye olde reverse duplicate for the sake of some pretense of organization on this tag and for searchability.