# Which way to synchronize vkQueueSubmit() to use?

Tags: c++, synchronization, vulkan

I have a function that copies data from one buffer to another, I need to synchronize its execution.
I have such a bad option:

```
void MainWindow::copyBuffer(VkBuffer srcBuffer, VkBuffer dstBuffer, VkDeviceSize size)
{
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    vkAllocateCommandBuffers(logicalDevice, &allocInfo, &commandBuffer);

    //Start recording
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);
    vkCmdCopyBuffer(commandBuffer, srcBuffer, dstBuffer, 1, &copyRegion);
    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    //Run command buffer
    vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    //Waiting for completion
    vkQueueWaitIdle(graphicsQueue);

    vkFreeCommandBuffers(logicalDevice, commandPool, 1, &commandBuffer);
}
```

This option is bad because if I want to execute the copyBuffer() function several times, then all the buffers will be copied strictly one at a time.

I want to use a fence for each function call so that multiple calls can run in parallel.

So far, I have only such a solution:

```
void MainWindow::copyBuffer(VkBuffer srcBuffer, VkBuffer dstBuffer, VkDeviceSize size)
{
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    vkAllocateCommandBuffers(logicalDevice, &allocInfo, &commandBuffer);
    
    //Create fence
    VkFenceCreateInfo fenceInfo{};
    fenceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FENCE_CREATE_INFO;
    fenceInfo.flags = VK_FENCE_CREATE_SIGNALED_BIT;

    VkFence executionCompleteFence = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    if (vkCreateFence(logicalDevice, &fenceInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &executionCompleteFence) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw MakeErrorInfo("Failed to create fence");
    }

    //Start recording
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);
    vkCmdCopyBuffer(commandBuffer, srcBuffer, dstBuffer, 1, &copyRegion);

    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    //Run command buffer
    vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    
    vkWaitForFences(logicalDevice, 1, &executionCompleteFence, VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
    vkResetFences(logicalDevice, 1, &executionCompleteFence);

    vkFreeCommandBuffers(logicalDevice, commandPool, 1, &commandBuffer);
    vkDestroyFence(logicalDevice, executionCompleteFence, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
}
```

Which of these options is better?
Is the second option written correctly?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65256272/vulkan-queue-submission-synchronization-vkwaitforfences-vs-vkqueuewaitidle bugs including... strange coincidinky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions are bad in the same way. They both block the CPU from doing anything until the transfer is done. And they both could be used to potentially submit multiple CBs to the same queue in the same frame, but with different submit commands.

Neither is desirable if performance is something you care about.

Ultimately, what you need to do is have your `copyBuffer` function not actually perform the copy. You should have a function which builds a command buffer to do a copy. That CB is then stored in a place to be submitted later with *other* copying CBs. Or better yet, you can have just one copying CB that each command adds to (the first one called in a frame will create the CB).

At some point in the future, before you've submitted the work that will use this data, you need to submit the transfer operations. And the way this works depends on if you're submitting the transfer operations on the same queue as the work that will consume them or not.

If they're on the same queue, then all you need to do is have an event in a command buffer at the end of your batch that synchronizes the transfer operations with their receivers. If you want to be more clever, each transfer operation can have its own event, which the receiving operations will wait on.

And in same-queue transfers, you also want to make sure that you submit the transfers in the same `vkQueueSubmit` call as the *rest* of your work. Or to put it another way, you should never make more than one call to `vkQueueSubmit` for a particular queue in a particular frame.

If you're dealing with separate queues, then things change. A bit. If timeline semaphores aren't an option, you'll need to submit your transfer work before you submit the receiving operations. This is because the transfer batch will need to signal a semaphore that the receiving operation will wait on. And a binary semaphore cannot be waited on until the operation that signals it has been submitted to a queue.

But otherwise, everything else stays the same. Of course, you don't need events since you're synchronizing by semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

The two functions are semantically identical and do exactly the same blocking behavior.

The second is slightly better. `vkQueueWaitIdle` is kind of a debug and out-of-hotspot feature. It might incur a hidden second submit to signal the implicit fence.

You don't need to reset fence that you subsequently destroy anyway. And you are creating it presignaled, which is a bug. Also you forgot to pass it to the `vkQueueSubmit`.